# PHP time() function returns the epoch instead of the current time

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following php code that is meant to format the current date and time:

```
$rawdatetime = time();
$datetime = date('Y-m-d', $rawdatetime) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', $rawdatetime) . '.000Z';
$this->debug($datetime);
```

The formatting seems to be working fine, but it keeps outputting that it is 1970; I get the following output:

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

My guess is that my server is not configured properly, but my Google search has not given me any clues. I am running WAMP if it helps.

Thanks in advance for any advice you may have.

EDIT: it seems that the date and time functions are working properly; but assigning them to a variable is what is the problem. Any work arounds to get the same formatting as above would be welcomed. But I would also like to know why this problem is happening.

Comment: FYI: The step of saving time() into a variable is superfluous, that's what date() defaults to using. Try simple echoing time() what do you get?

Comment: what does `var_dump(time());` yield?

Comment: Thanks Jessica, but there is a very small chance that if it is running near midnight the date and time will not match if I do it your way.

Comment: ... it might be that you did not specify a default timezone in your php config

Comment: run `echo date("c");` what do you have ?

Comment: @GordonM     int(1371654016)

Comment: and what output do you have with: `echo date('Y-m-d', 1371654016);` ?

Comment: @Baba a var dump gives me: string(25) "2013-06-19T15:06:29+00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to use `time()` at all here, because `date()` will use the current time as the default value if you don't pass a value to that parameter.

Secondly, you're using two separate `date()` calls, separated by a `"T"`. Note that the formatting for `date()` can accept a hard-coded character like `T`; you just need to escape them with backslashes, so you don't need to split it into two function calls.

Your entire code could look like this:

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d \T H:i:s.\0\0\0\Z');
```

Which gives `2013-06-19 T 11:18:53.000Z`

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. But I am still curious as to why it did not work when I used the other approach.

Comment: Something tells me that you just had a typo in your real code in the `$rawdatetime` variable name and the  undefined var evaluated to zero

Comment: yeah, it does sound like a typo. PHP may have its faults, but it certainly doesn't have the kind of basic variable handling issues you're describing. It would have got anywhere if it had that kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me (when echoing, instead of `$this->debug`). So either you somehow have a faulty PHP version, or the problem is not in your code sample. This is what I did:

```
<?php

$rawdatetime = time();
$datetime = date('Y-m-d', $rawdatetime) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', $rawdatetime) . '.000Z';
echo $datetime,"\n";
```